# Can't access certain files on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, directory, server, locale

I am starting to learn the basics of the Ubuntu Server.

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS server and I connect to it through SSH(with putty). the problem is I can't access some directories(No such file or directory error), and I can't execute some commands (cat /etc/deafult/locale/). 
Here's an example which works:

```
cd /etc/
```

on the other hand, trying to acsess

```
cd /etc/deafult/
```

shows an "No such file or directory" error. (even though I can see "deafult" directory when I type "ls".

I get the same error when I try to check the locale (with cat /etc/deafult/locale).

I did look for some answers such as updating the locale, but it did not work. I figured maybe it's something else.
Thank you so much for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you only one account, these are still system files that require "root" access. Try using sudo:

```
sudo cat /etc/default/locale
```

Also, it could just be a spelling error if you are accidentally typing "deafult" instead of "default".

Comment: Yes that solved it for me, I feel kinda stupid. Another question if I may: for some reason when I check my locale I see two lines instead of one: "LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE="en_US:en" and I realize should only see the first one, or maybe I am just wrong? (I am using a tutorial which states that you should only see 1 line, which is "
LANG=en_US.UTF-8")

Comment: These are actually distinct lines. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale#LANG:_default_locale

Please mark this answer as correct. Thanks!